# Why is my link clickable as big as my parent and not as big as the img inside of it?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an `<a>` (no given width) within a `<div>.container` (100% width) and it contains an `<img />` (200px width). I want the `<a>` to have only the width of the `<img />` so that you can't click the entire width of the `<div>.container` (100%).

**Without success I tried:**

- Changing the container div's width (works for the link but it has to be 100% so doesn't work as I want)
- Changing the width of the `<a>` to 200px.

Demo can be seen here:

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75974339/bsl/index.html)

***NOTE:*** The website is responsive so make sure the width of the screen is less than 768px and then open the menu)

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Wouldnt it be a good idea to put ``<img>`` inside ``<a>`` rather than putting it inside ``<div>``

Comment: @AdityaSethi Thanks for the insight, that was exactly what I was looking for. I like to put everything in div's even though I shouldn't!

Comment: @AdityaSethi it changed a lot of the dropdown menu's position, so I just put the `<div>` outside of the `<a>` and `<img`>. Now it works as I want ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is given by the height of your `#menu_contact`:

```
#menu_contact {
    background: url("../images/contact_background.png") no-repeat;
    width: 175px;
    height: 80px; /* changed - previously 155px */
    padding-top: 75px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 46px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Update**

For the width 100% of menu's entries, try to do this changes:

```
.menu_item {
    margin-top: 35px;
    padding-left: 35px; /* from margin to padding */
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 35px; /* new property */
}

.divider {
    width: 10px;
    height: 63px;
    background-image: url("../images/divider.png");
    float: left;
    /* margin-left: 35px; */
    margin-top: 35px;
}
```

Comment: You have to make the screen's width to under `768px` and then look at: `body` > `div.container` > `a[href="#home"]` > `div.logo`. I'm talking about that `div.container`, `<a>` and `<img/>`. The dividers aren't shown at this Media Query width.